# how to automatically output last day of the year in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

without hardcoding, how can I automatically get 12/31 of last year, 12/31 of two years ago and 12/31 of three years ago? I am using Big Query. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [LAST_DAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#last_day):

```
SELECT 
    LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), YEAR),
    LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), YEAR),
    LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR), YEAR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: every year has very same last day - 12/31, so you can simply use

```
select 
  date(2020,12,31), 
  date(2019,12,31), 
  date(2018,12,31)
```

Obviously, `LAST_DAY` is still very useful when looking for similar info for MONTH or WEEK etc.